# Is there any python module to assign secondary structures which includes both Polyprolene region as well as individual strand as well?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb, secondary-structure

I wanted to assign secondary structure to set of pdb files. However, DSSP and STRIDE cannot assign for single peptides if it is falling inside single long beta strand or polyprolene region as it does not have any hydrogen bond.DSSP and STRIDE work fine as long as the peptides form hydrogen bonds.

Can someone suggest me a way to assign secondary structure for peptides which also fall in the region of PPII and beta strand region ?